# How to use inputs inside a dynamic component using the :is binding with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Let me preface this question by stating I am new to Vue.js and am trying to get a hold of the syntax after reading the "Essentials" documentation and I am open to having any or all of this change.

With that being said is there a way to use inputs inside a dynamic component using the :is binding with Vue.js.

See the fiddle below:
https://jsfiddle.net/tyq30sft/

I am trying to get the edit button to allow editing of the data being populated by v-for in a single component tag. I have tried several solutions but have had no results.

I believe the issue lies in this code but cant find the solution:

```
v-on:input="$emit('input', $event.target.info.name)"
```

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Here is a working version; but I'm not sure I like the results completely. https://jsfiddle.net/vhdtr7fe/

Comment: Kind of like this a little better. https://jsfiddle.net/Lksrk038/1/

Comment: I should also mention that this option is likely easiest but some people would object to it because technically a prop is being modified. https://jsfiddle.net/uwbkua4L/

Comment: Wow! Thanks! I love how easy the last one is. Thanks for all the options it really helps me understand!